# Create ListView using a string of text and a string of images using picasso

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I need to create a listView in Android Studio that has a text and an image corresponding to that text. I am aware I have to make my own custom adapter, however I don't know how to make it with more than just the text view in each row. The adapter would take in a string array of the text and another string array of the url's that correspond to the pictures. How can I create this adapter to do this. I'd preferably like to use Picasso, but if you have any other suggestions that works too.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {
Context context;
String[] descriptionArray;
String[] url;


MyAdapter (Context c, String[] importerArray,String[] url) {
    super(c, R.layout.content_orders,R.id.textView2, importerArray);
    this.context =c;
    this.descriptionArray = importerArray;
    this.url = url;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_orders, list, false);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    description.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
    Picasso.with(OrdersActivity.this).load(url[position]).into(myImage);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Thank you.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin I apologize. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BaseAdapter and  Bean

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Bean> mList;

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use converview recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_demo, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

}
}
```

add class Bean

```
public class Bean {
String text;
String url;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
ArrayList<Bean> list=new ArrayList<>();
Bean bean1=new Bean;
bean1.setText("YOUR TEXT");
bean1.setUrl("IMAGE URL");
//and bean2……3……4……
list.add(bean1);
//add(bean2)…………
MyAdapter adapter =new MyAdapter(this,list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How can I add both the text and the image from their respective arrays to the bean list? I'm sorry just a bit new to this whole process.

Comment: Essentially, I assume in my main activity class I have to make a variable List<Bean> myList = new ArrayList<>();   What is it that I would write in my Main Activity Class to populate myList with the information from both the text and url string arrays?